# How do I generate a variable number of variables?

Tags: r, loops, variables

I am working with a loop that has internal loops. in every internal loop a number x of time series is created (ts1, ts2, ts3,... tsx) and then I need to bind them using cbind (data.f=cbind(ts1, ts2, ts3,... tsx)) in order to plot data.f and see all the time series created in the same plot. 
The problem is that in every cycle the number of time series created (x) changes, so the command:

```
data.f=cbind(ts1, ts2, ts3,... tsx)
```

will have every time a different number of terms "tsi". How can i define in my general loop this command that includes all the tsx created in the internal loops when i dont know the number of them every time?

Comment: It is better to use a list instead of a bunch of objects. If the number of objects come from a loop you have to substitute the loop by `lapply()`, `sapply()` or `replicate()` (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Try `do.call` and `cbind` as below

```
total <- abs(round(rnorm(1) * 20))
ts_final <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:total,function(x){
   as.xts(1:10,Sys.Date()-1:10)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself appending numbers to your variable names, you need to stop in the track and rethink your code: you should be using a vector or list instead.

In your particular case, create a list of time series instead of individual variables, and collate them into a table using `dplyr::bind_cols(time_series)` or `do.call(cbind, time_series)`.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad Rudolph! fixed!